# How to set up GRUB to triple boot: Ubuntu, Windows 7 and Joli OS?

Tags: dual-boot

I've a laptop with Windows 7 preinstalled. I shrunk Windows drive to install Ubuntu 12.04 from a Live USB.

But after installation, I am not seeing the GRUB menu. How to fix this?

Also I will be installing [Joli OS](http://www.jolicloud.com/jolios). So I want a GRUB menu with all the three OS's listed. Finally how can I change the order of GRUB menu after it appears.